# the total no. of rows after sorting by month and year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on a c# project in that I have made this query which is:

```
SELECT Sum(pric_ecolumn) 
FROM   table2 
WHERE  Datepart(mm, record_column) = @yourMonthSelected 
AND    Datepart(yy, record_column) = @yourYearSelected
```

It returns the sum of the price column in particular month and year. which is type of sorting but I also want how many rows so apart from the 
`sum(price_column)` which is function of SQL Server is there any function which returns the total number of rows I can make two queries and work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT`:

```
SELECT SUM(pric_ecolumn)  AS Total_Price,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM   table2 
WHERE  Datepart(mm, record_column) = @yourMonthSelected 
AND    Datepart(yy, record_column) = @yourYearSelected
```

Comment: sir but here you have used AS what is the use of assingning totalprice and count? i am using winform and c# so does it is usable in that?

Comment: @shariq_khan: That are just aliases for the columns. Since you have used aggregation functions to count or sum the field of all rows matching the `WHERE`-clause, you should specify an alias. You can, however, use the same name as the column. So change `Total_Price` to `pric_ecolumn` if you want. It's just a matter of readability.

Comment: no no. it is working perfectly but if i remove both the AS part then it will also work? right?

Comment: @shariq_khan: You should always specify a column alias if you don't select a column directly(f.e. `SELECT pric_ecolumn FROM table2`). Otherwise the name is unpredictable. Note that you can also use a different syntax for column aliases: `SELECT RowCount = COUNT(*) ...` ( so the name first followed by `=`).